# map runSTArray over a list of STArrays?

Tags: arrays, haskell, state, higher-rank-types

I have a function that creates recursively a flattened list of matrices from a tree that have to be mutable as their elements are updated often during their creation. So far I have come up with a recursive solution that has the signature:

```
doAll :: .. -> [ST s (STArray s (Int, Int) Int)]
```

The reason I do not return the `[UArray (Int,Int) Int]` directly is because `doAll` is called recursively, modifies elements of the matrices in the list and appends new matrices. I don't want to freeze and thaw the matrices unnecessarily.

So far so good. I can inspect the `n`-th matrix  (of type `Array (Int, Int) Int`) in `ghci`

```
runSTArray (matrices !! 0)
runSTArray (matrices !! 1)
```

and indeed I get the correct results for my algorithm. However, I didn't find a way to map `runSTUArray` over the list that is returned by `doAll`:

```
map (runSTArray) matrices

Couldn't match expected type `forall s. ST s (STArray s i0 e0)'
            with actual type `ST s0 (STArray s0 (Int, Int) Int)'
```

The same problem happens if I try to evaluate recursively over the list or try to evaluate single elements wrapped in a function

Could someone please explain what is going on (I didn't really understand the implications of the `forall` keyword) and how I could evaluate the arrays in the list?

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg47957.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an unfortunate consequence of the type trick that makes `ST` safe.  First, you need to know how ST works.  The only way to get from the `ST` monad to pure code is with the `runST` function, or other functions built upon it like `runSTArray`.  These are all of the form `forall s.`.  This means that, in order to construct an Array from an STArray, the compiler must be able to determine that it can substitute any type it likes in for the `s` type variable inside `runST`.

Now consider the function `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.  This shows that every element in the list must have exactly the same type (`a`), and therefore also the same `s`.  But this extra constraint violates the type of `runSTArray`, which declares that the compiler must be able to freely substitute other values for `s`.

You can work around this by defining a new function to first freeze the arrays inside the ST monad, then run the resulting ST action:

```
runSTArrays :: Ix ix => (forall s. [ST s (STArray s ix a)]) -> [Array ix a]
runSTArrays arrayList = runST $ (sequence arrayList >>= mapM freeze)
```

Note the `forall` requires the `RankNTypes` extension.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this makes a lot of sense. I have to remove the `runST` in your `runSTArrays`, though, and call it later separately however. `ghc` cannot deduce the context and also doesn't accept an explicit type annotation.

Comment: Sorry about that; I've added the appropriate type annotation to this code.  GHC doesn't deduce higher-kinded type annotations (the forall), so it needs to be provided manually.

Comment: Is `sequence` there a placeholder for where the program would have "some functions to update the arrays contents"?

Comment: @misterbee - no, `sequence` is there to convert the list of `ST s (STArray s ix a)` actions into a single ST action that produces a list of STArrays.  If functions to update the array contents are necessary (I don't believe they are for the OP), they would go into the function passed to mapM, such as `mapM (\array -> updateArray array >> freeze array)`.

Comment: @John L, and thanks. I asked because I have a similar case to OP, where I want to efficiently update many values in a pair of STArrays, in an "mdo" sort of way, where later changes are dependent on earlier changes (the arrays are basically representing state-space for a search algorithm)

Answer (score 4):

You just bounced against the limitations of the type system.

The runSTArray has a higher ranked type. You must pass it a ST-action whose state type variable is unique. Yet, in Haskell it is normally not possible to have such values in lists.

The whole thing is a clever scheme to make sure that values you produce in an ST action can't escape from there. Which means, it looks like your design is somehow broken.

One suggestion: can't you process the values in another ST action, like

```
sequence [ ... your ST s (STArray s x) ...] >>= processing
  where
     processing :: [STArray s x] -> ST s (your results)
```

Comment: I'd be interested in which sense my design could be broken (not that I doubt it, I'm pretty much new to haskell). Do you have some suggestions of how to manage a growing list of mutable matrices to be passed around and evaluated?

Comment: @bbtrb - Maybe it's not the design per se but the desire to work with a list of `ST s ...` things. Basically, such matrices are mutable data, and this means you can't (or at least shouldn't) work with them outside ST or IO actions. Exactly this is enforced by the type of the runST* family of funtions, like John L told you. `freeze` is merely a way to tell the Haskell system that henceforth you want to treat the matrices (or whatever) as read-only values and  then it lets escape (copies of) values constructed in a ST action.